# How to make a UIBarButtonItem selectable on a UIToolbar part of a UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a two column UIPickerView in a project that I am working on, and I successfully created the UIPickerView, UIToolBar, and UIToolBarItem programmatically.  However the toolbar item isn't responding to touch inputs.  I have tried on the device and in the Simulator, and the selector method is never being called / reached.

```
_pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 216)];

UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *btnAddCredit = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addCreditToUser:)];
NSLog(@"btnAddCredit %hhd",btnAddCredit.isEnabled);

[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flex,btnAddCredit,nil]];

toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true;

[_pickerView addSubview:toolBar];

_pickerView.delegate = self;
_pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

[self.parentViewController.view addSubview:_pickerView];
```

Here's a quick animated GIF explaining what is happening,
[image]

Comment: try adding a custom button on toolbar.

Comment: try to use self.parentViewController.view (or other view which you can create) as superview for both _pickerView and toolBar

Comment: why are you sure that the selector is not called? could you show the method `addCreditToUser:`